# How can I get image from hardware trigger in Labview with IMAQx?

Tags: triggers, hardware, labview

first of all thanks a lot for reading this post and being able to help.

I have a Basler camera which is triger by a digital output of a PLC (hardware trigger).

Well, now I would like to get the image in a display when camera is triggered.

How can I do that? Is there any vi which is waitting for new image of the camara and then get it? How can I nottice that camera is triggered?

thanks a lot. any help will be appreciate it!!!

Comment: I don't know enough about IMAQ to know whether it supports what you want to do, but you will probably have more success asking this on the NI forums and giving more detail about which camera it is, how it is connected and so on. However one option could be to read the trigger with a digital input connected to the PC instead, and acquire the image under software control? That would depend how critical the timing is, of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!
I have just fixed it! 
I asked the question in NI forums!